# Hover effect when mousing over table cell dividers HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have the current following table:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Plum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>1:1</td>
    <td>1:2</td>
    <td>1:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>2:1</td>
    <td>1:1</td>
    <td>1,5:1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plum</td>
    <td>1:3</td>
    <td>2:1</td>
    <td>1:1</td>
  </tr>
```

I am looking to cause a trigger when I am mousing over the cell **dividers** , AS indicated bellow. This needs to be done in either HTML/CSS/jss. I can easily figure out a hover for the table or for the individual cells, but how could I get something to trigger when hovering over the cell dividers? (see following image)

[image: image 1]

Comment: have you tried to use hover on `tr` instead of `td` ?

Comment: Can you please explain how is this related to `Java`?

Comment: On a sidenote, java and javascript are two very different things

Comment: I don't think there is a hover (onfocus || onclick) handler for cell dividers.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr td{
  position:relative;
}
tr td::after{
  position:absolute;
  right:-2px; 
  width:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  top:0px;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
}
tr td::nth-last-of-type::after{
  display:none;
}
```

Now you can trigger anything by selecting 'tr td::after' as a selector

Also, width and right can be changed according to your border/padding of the cells.